# Is there any C++ IDE that supports TextMate-Like Snippets?

Tags: c++, ide

I'm currently using Code::Blocks for develop C++ programs.

But I miss the nice bundles from SublimeText or Gedit with Plugins.
Is there any C++ IDE that allows using Bundles ? Or any Code::Block plugin for that ?

Thanks.

**edit:** A snippet is when you type "class", and press tab for example: that will create for you the code for the class, so you don't need to type the full code.

Comment: Can you explain what a bundle is? That would allow Code::Blocks users that never used TextMate to answer, giving you a larger audience.

Comment: @Martinho Done, hope it explains it well

Comment: @Tamás Oh... yes, I thought there were called "bundles"

Comment: vim+ultisnips+clang-complete. ditch those IDEs, they all have no good editors ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I use Linux, and I'm thinking in use VIM, maybe when I have more free time.

Comment: @dysoco If you decide to do so, I suggest to read Steve Losh's fantastic post about it: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not an IDE, Vim has [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) which I use constantly for my code. There's also [snippetsemu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1318) which I have not tried but have heard good things about.

Comment: Thanks, I really like VIM, and I was searching for Addons like those.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Netbeans (the number of times I say this... :) ) anyways, it has a nice feature called "Code Templates" - you can populate this with a list of whatever you want, type the characters and hit tab, and it will fill it in, is that what you are looking for?